# ASP.NET random slow downs

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

We are experiencing random intermittent slow-downs in our ASP.NET application. Most pages take between 100-500ms to render (depending on which modules are used on the page). Occasionally however - perhaps 1 in 100 requests, these figures are more like 5000-10000ms. This is not a database related issue - I have checked for slow queries, and is not related to the complexity of the page - e.g. a page which takes 100ms is just as likely to take 10000ms when it slows down. I don't think the app-pool is recycling either - would normally see this in task manager.  Could it possibly be GC? Any ideas? The w3wp application usually uses a steady 800MB-1GB of memory at all times.

Thanks
Marcus

Comment: some really good suggestions there. Thanks guys - looks like I have some investigations to do!!!

Comment: Did you find the cause for the same ? I am also facing similar issue. At times the request just takes to long. Refreshing the page brings things back to normal. This happens with the fastest page available as well...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best thing I can tell you to do is to attach a profiler (search this site for a good .NET profiler, I personally use [ANTS](http://www.red-gate.com/Products/ants_profiler/index.htm)) to identify bottlenecks.  Without good profile data all of our suggestions here will simply be speculation.

Comment: Is it recommended to use profilers in production? I'm looking for cheaper/freer alternatives to paid APM tools. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Does the application use the Cache at all for maintaining a large piece of static data?  Even if the app-pool is not recycling, it's possible that some large objects in cache are being expired and then the next hit that requires that Cache has to refill it.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Tess Ferrandez](http://blogs.msdn.com/tess/), (ASP.NET Escalation Engineer) you're at that magic point on a 32bit server where you are likely to start seeing Out of Memory Exceptions - it's possible that this is having an affect too.

She has a number of useful posts on this topic:

1. [TechEd Resources](http://blogs.msdn.com/tess/archive/2008/11/21/slides-and-resources-for-teched-presentations-about-debugging-net-issues-with-windbg.aspx)
2. [Debugging Memory](http://blogs.msdn.com/tess/archive/2008/02/15/net-debugging-demos-lab-3-memory.aspx)
3. [Debugging Memory Leaks](http://blogs.msdn.com/tess/archive/2008/03/17/net-debugging-demos-lab-6-memory-leak.aspx)

As others have also said, profilers, and tracing will also help.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried running your web application in in-proc session state mode, and see if there is any difference?