# ASP.NET MVC intermittent slow response

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis-7

**Problem**

In our production environment, system occasionally delays the page response of an ASP.NET MVC application up to 30 seconds or so, even though same page renders in 2-3 seconds most of the times. This happens randomly with any arbitrary page, and GET or POST type requests. For example, log files indicates, system took 15 seconds to complete a request for jquery script file or for other small css file it took 10 secs.

Similar Problems:

1. [Random Slow Downs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/650618/asp-net-random-slow-downs)

**Production Environment:**

1. Windows Server 2008 - Standard (32-bit) - App Pool running in integrated mode.
2. ASP.NET MVC 1.0

We have tried followings/observations:

1. Moved the application to a stand alone web server, but, it didn't help.
2. We didn't ever notice same issue on the server for any 'ASP.NET' application.
3. App Pool settings are fine. No abrupt recycles/shutdowns.
4. No cpu spikes or memory problems.
5. No delays due to SQL queries or so.
6. Converting App Pool to classic mode didn't help either

It seems as something causing delay along HTTP Pipeline or worker processor seeing the request late.

Looking for other suggestions.

-- Thanks

Comment: This is much more likely an IIS or server issue than an MVC issue, IMO. FWIW, I only see this type of behavior when the app has been unloaded...and it occurs with all types of ASP.NET apps.

Comment: This happens also even if application is running. We are monitoring app pool starts and shutdowns as well.

Comment: It might also be garbage collection.  You might need to recycle the app pool a bit more often.

Comment: @arehman, Consider asking this on serverfault.com. That's where the system admins and IT professionals are. You should get better answers there. Voting this for migration to serverfault.

Comment: Try putting an httpmodule that intercepts and logs **every** step of the request pipeline. That should tell you if the problem is with .NET or with IIS.

Comment: We are experiencing random timeouts and log files do not indicate anything about such requests. App Pool idle time out is 60 minutes and timeout can happen lets say after 15 mins. of logging in. There is not much terrific to site also.

Comment: @Mauricio: Putting HTTP Module to log time elapsed after each event didn't help. It means worker processor is behaving right. Also, http sys log doesn't indicate anything of interest

Comment: @arehman - Did you find the solution ? I have recently started experiencing the issue. Earlier it was perfectly working fine

Answer (score 1):

Sorry if this is too obvious but have you checked IIS? for Process recycling, you can set it so it recycles once a day at a set time .

You could also try application warm up http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2010/01/31/asp-net-4-0-how-to-use-application-warm-up-class.aspx